# How can I pass null to an external library, using ctypes, with an argument declared with ctypeslib.ndpointer?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, ctypes

Inspired by another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31933128/505088) here, I have a ctypes function that I am calling using `ctypeslib.ndpointer`:

```
lib.foo.argtypes = [ctypeslib.ndpointer(np.complex64, ndim=1, flags='C'), POINTER(c_int)]
```

The external function is declared like so:

```
void foo(cmplx_float *array, int *length)
```

My problem is that I want to call the function twice. The first time I want to pass `nullptr` to the `array` argument, so that I can find out the required length. Then the second time, I will pass in a numpy array.

So I do so like this:

```
lib.foo(None, length)
```

This fails with the following error:

> ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: : argument must be an ndarray

Is it possible for me to pass `nullptr`?

Comment: I'm a little rusty on `ctypes`, but it looks like if you [create the pointer without any arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#pointers), it should create a null pointer.

Comment: Probably the most clean option is to subclass the type returned by `ctypeslib.ndpointer`, which itself is a subclass of [`ctypeslib._ndptr`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.2/numpy/ctypeslib.py#L150). Override its `from_param` class method to return `obj` if it's `None`, otherwise return the result of calling the parent's `from_param` method.

Comment: Alternatively you could temporarily modify `argtypes`, but I don't like that since it's not thread safe. You could also create a second function pointer instance that uses `argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(c_int)]`, but requiring two function pointers is clumsy.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks. I'm changing the argtypes declaration right now, but it's threadsafe because the function pointer is local to my wrapper method. But I don't like it. I'll try your first option tomorrow when I have a clear head.

Comment: Does a new instance of `lib` get created for every method call? Otherwise if `lib` is global or a class/instance attribute, then `lib.foo` is cached and not local to your method. To create a new function pointer each time, instantiate a prototype with a tuple of `(name, lib)`. For example: `foo = CFUNCTYPE(restype, ctypeslib.ndpointer(np.complex64, ndim=1, flags='C'), POINTER(c_int))(('foo', lib))`. The `CFUNCTYPE` function caches the prototype, so it's more efficient than it appears to be.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks again for that, you've really helped me here. I succeeded in implementing the class factory approach with an override to `from_param` which works perfectly. I can't thank you enough. You truly are the SO master of ctypes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If (like me) you are dealing with multiple different array types, a slightly nicer workaround is to wrap `ndpointer` itself:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

def wrapped_ndptr(*args, **kwargs):
  base = ndpointer(*args, **kwargs)
  def from_param(cls, obj):
    if obj is None:
      return obj
    return base.from_param(obj)
  return type(base.__name__, (base,), {'from_param': classmethod(from_param)})

ComplexArrayType = wrapped_ndptr(dtype=np.complex128, ndim=1, flags='C_CONTIGUOUS')
DoubleArrayType = wrapped_ndptr(dtype=np.float64, ndim=1, flags='C_CONTIGUOUS')
```

Comment: That looks quite slick. I'll try it out because I am in fact doing exactly the same as you!

Answer (score 1):

Following the excellent advice from eryksun in a comment I subclassed the type returned by `ctypeslib.ndpointer` and implemented an overridden `from_param`. This is a little tricky as it has to be done using class factory techniques, because the class returned by `ctypeslib.ndpointer` is made by a factory.

The code that I ended up with:

```
_ComplexArrayTypeBase = numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=numpy.complex128, ndim=1,
    flags='C_CONTIGUOUS')

def _from_param(cls, obj):
    if obj is None:
        return obj
    return _ComplexArrayTypeBase.from_param(obj)

ComplexArrayType = type(
    'ComplexArrayType',
    (_ComplexArrayTypeBase,),
    {'from_param': classmethod(_from_param)}
)
```

Many thanks to eryksun for his (as always) expert advice.

Comment: This two-pass call pattern is so common that `_ndptr.from_param`  should really already handle this. Consider suggesting this small change to the NumPy devs.